# System Restore points disappear

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

While reinstalling Windows 10, I tried for the first time to do restore points as I added apps and configuration.

I added system protection only to the C: drive that has the OS. Other than that I increased the amount of space allocated to the system protection. I have not done any kind of system cleaning or tweaking.

I've added three, but now I checked and it says there are none. How could they have disappeared? And how can I trust restore points?

Comment: When reinstalling Windows, either via a clean install or repair install, the installation process removes all checkpoints from `C:\System Volume Information`, otherwise it would result in OS instability.  Windows 10 has always had issues taking regular System Restore checkpoints, so I always recommend using Task Scheduler to create backups at [regular intervals](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/System%20Restore), such as upon every reboot or every few days, combined with a minimum of 30GB for restore point storage.

Comment: They where made after reinstalling win

Comment: What method did you use to create the restore point(s)? AFAIK, Windows will only delete restore points if when creating a new one, available space set for restore points isn't enough for the restore point _(it may be possible that new checkpoint could have exceeded the available space available, even after removing prior restore points - not sure if that's a correct supposition or not)_. You may want to review the Event Viewer logs to see if the removal was logged _(not sure what log to view, but you should be able to find the correct Event Viewer log to checkout via google or Microsoft Docs)_